# Killing a process in cmd or shell using a script

Tags: windows, shell, process, batch-file, cmd

How to implement using a shell or command line script in Windows that checks for the status of some process, ie. Tomcat server and if it exists, it kills it?

Comment: Why is this tagged with Python? Are Python solutions accepted?

Comment: No, it's not, just shell scripting if possible. I have no idea from where to start about this. I don't know how to catch that specific process, ie. I don't know how to get it by name. Does that function even exist in shell scripting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On window you can make a `.bat` file with this content:

```
TASKKILL /F /IM "program_name.exe"
```

replace program_name with the program you want to kill. Here's a decent article on [`TASKKILL`](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/kill-windows-process-with-taskkill-command/)

Or if it's just tomcat you can run [`shutdown.bat`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/tomcat-ug.html#tomcat_scripts)... if `TOMCAT_HOME` isn't set just run it from the tomcat home directory.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I have been looking for. :)

Comment: @Takarakaka - If it spawns other processes, add the `/t` switch. Plus unless the program name has a space in it, the quotes are unnecessary. `taskkill /f /t /im programName.exe` is good enough. Also, wildcards are accepted, so you could do `taskkill /f /t /im programName*` to forcefully kill all threads with names starting with `programName` and any child processes they spawned.

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much :D

Comment: Just in case anyone else is running this on Windows in Bash, you need to use - instead of / for the arguments (so TASKKILL -F -IM "program_name.exe")